# Reading ASCII-encoded files with Ruby 1.9 in a UTF-8 environment

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, ascii, ruby-1.9

I just upgraded from Ruby 1.8 to 1.9, and most of my text processing scripts now fail with the error `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`. I need to either strip out the invalid characters or specify that Ruby should use ASCII encoding instead (or whatever encoding the C `stdio` functions write, which is how the files were produced) -- how would I go about doing either of those things?

Preferably the latter, because (as near as I can tell) there's nothing wrong with the files on disk -- if there are weird, invalid characters they don't appear in my editor...

Comment: is it possible to change the title of the question? Since the answer is not for the question anymore. Cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your locale set to in the shell?  In Linux-based systems you can check this by running the `locale` command and change it by e.g.

```
$ export LANG=en_US
```

My guess is that you are using locale settings which have UTF-8 encoding and this is causing Ruby to assume that the text files were created according to utf-8 encoding rules.  You can see this by trying

```
$ LANG=en_GB ruby -e 'warn "foo".encoding.name'
US-ASCII
$ LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 ruby -e 'warn "foo".encoding.name'
UTF-8
```

For a more general treatment of how string encoding has changed in Ruby 1.9 I thoroughly recommend 
http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string

(code examples assume bash or similar shell - C-shell derivatives are different)

Comment: Excellent. I guess this is my karmic punishment for slinging strings around in C without caring about the encoding, or for being a native English speaker.

Comment: @Doches: So, *you're* the guy who writes all those apps that won't let me use my actual name. BTW: admitting you have a problem is the first ... bla bla bla :-)